# A basic code example of the difference between a method and a function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, methods

I always have difficulty grasping new concepts without seeing a real, basic, working example of what I am reading about. While I like the [other explanation on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155609/what-is-the-difference-between-a-method-and-a-function), I'd really like to see a very basic example showing the difference between methods and functions in JavaScript that I can quickly run to learn more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `method` is just a function that is a `property` of an object.  It's not a different type of object in javascript, but rather `method` is just the descriptive name given to a `function` that is defined as a `property` of an object.

```
var myObj = {};
myObj.go = function() {alert("hi");}
myObj.go();
```

In this example, `go` is a method on the `myObj` object.

When a method is called as in the above example `myObj.go()`, then the value of the `this` pointer is set to the object that was involved in the invocation of the method (in this case `myObj`).

Since global functions are also implicitly properties on the `window` object, one could say that global functions are also methods on the `window` object, but you do not need the `window` designation in order to call them.

Local functions like `inner()` in this function are just functions and not methods as they are not attached to a particular object:

```
function main() {
    function inner() {
        alert("hi");
    }
    inner();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a function and a function call:

```
function myFunction(){
    alert("This is a function!");
}

myFunction();
```

This, on the other end, is a method call, because it is a member function of an object.

```
message.toUpperCase();
```

Here's the full code to create a class/methods and a call:

```
function Circle(x,y,r) {
  this.xcoord = x;
  this.ycoord = y;
  this.radius = r;
}
Circle.prototype.retArea = function () {
  return ( Math.PI * this.radius * this.radius );
};

var aCircle = new Circle(1,2,3); 
var a = aCircle.retArea();
```

Comment: Technically, not quite.  In JavaScript, functions you declare "globally" are still properties of an object, namely, the global object.  In common usage, you can say this, because no one ever really calls global functions for the purpose of accessing or mutating other properties on the global object.

Comment: Point given. But I assumed OP was looking for examples for the common simple answer. ;-) (based on the link he provided)

Comment: That's fair.  Yes, for the usual case your answer is helpful.

Comment: How do I execute the example with the function Circle(). I thought it would have been just a case of adding an additional line alert(Circle.prototype.returnArea); but when I add this it outputs the entire function () code.

Comment: You'd have to create a Circle object. See my edit (at the end of the post!)! :-)

Comment: Sorry as a beginner in JavaScript, I'm still not sure what else I'd have to add on to this to get this example to work.

Comment: Well, the example should work on it's own! But you need to display `a` to see something ;-) Try to add `alert( a );` at the end of the script :-)

Answer (score 0):

example:

function:

```
var f1 = function fBase() { ... }

function f2() { ... }

var f3 = function() { ... }

f1()
f2()
f3()
```

method:

```
var c = function oBase() { 

   this.method1 = function() { ... };

}

c.prototype.method2 = function() { ... }

var o = new c()
o.method1()
o.method2()
```

method json:

```
var o = { method1: function() { ... } }
o.method2 = function() { ... }

o.method1()
o.method2()
```

Answer (score 0):

A function is a type which can be used to define a piece of code that can be executed by using call ("()") operator and may return data to the caller.

e.g.

define

```
function sayHello(){
 return "Hello";
}
```

use

```
var result = sayHello();
```

Now, result will contian "Hello".

A method is a function that is defined inside an object and accessible through a property. For example, **`slice`** is function defined over all string instances

e.g.

define

```
var obj = {
 sayHello : function(){
  return "Hello";
 }
};
```

you can also define methods outside the object definition

```
var obj = {};
obj.sayHello = function(){
      return "Hello";
     };
```

use

```
var result = obj.sayHello();
```

We use methods in object oriented programming.

Refer:

- [Functions at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Functions)
- [Objects at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)